# Z-index not applying in FireFox with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I have checked some of the other questions here and most of them mention that `z-index` issues for firefox tend to relate to the fact that one of the items is not `position:Absolute`.

```
<div id="AnimatedBanner" style="right:-5px;">
                        <object style="position:absolute; z-index:-1" width=" 1175" height="400" data="images/AnimatedBanner.swf"></object>
                    </div>
                    <div class="banner_text" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;">
</div>
```

However it always lays the `Animatedbanner` on top of the `banner_text`. It works perfectly fine in all of the other browsers but I'm still not sure why it won't work in firefox.

Comment: So, what task are you trying to solve in general?

Comment: I would like the banner_text to lay on top of the AnimatedBanner.

Comment: Do you see black square over red one http://codepen.io/anon/pen/chGgd ?

Comment: Yes, that does show in FF as the black on top of the red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bit searching i found the solution should be setting "wmode" to "transparent" , so your code should be :

```
<object style="position:absolute; z-index:-1" width=" 1175" height="400" data="images/AnimatedBanner.swf">
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

You can test this fiddle on ff:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/h56q3n09/3/

Comment: This does not cause it to work inside Firefox. I attempted this as well.

Comment: @samiracle please check my fiddle.

Comment: this works! thanks, where did you find this just for future reference?